# If $f '(2) = 0$ and $f ''(2) = 4$, what can you say about $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I was doing very well in Calculus up until this point.  I realize that concavity and $f'$ and $f''$ require one to really visualize what is happening with a function, but can someone please help me to understand this problem?

In particular, the second part of the question ask this:

So, if $f'(2) = 0$ and $f''(2) = 4$, what can you say about $f$?

What I know is this: if the $f'(2) = 0$, then $f$ has either a local maximum or minimum.  $f''(2) = 4$ is greater than $0$, so I believe this means the graph is concave upward.  So does this mean that the graph has a local minimum?  If yes, is there any easier way to visualize these problems so that I can become more effective at solving them?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The first two derivatives tell you what the approximating **parabola** at $x=a$ looks like. And you know what $y=2(x-2)^2$ looks like.

Comment: $f''(2)>0$ hence $f'$ is increasing near $2$ and therefore it is negative "right before" $2$ ($f$ decreases) and positive "right after" $2$ so ($f$ increases) so the point is indeed a local minimum.

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't really understand what f'' is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it has a local minimum; and I'm not sure it's possible to give an easier way of getting the answer than the one and a half lines it took you!

One thing you might say is that this is all about "what $f(x)$ looks like near $x=2$", and that the answer is that you're looking for the [parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) which most closely fits with $f$ near this point.

This is a part of *Taylor's thorem*, which tells us here that
$$f(x) \approx f(2) + (x-2) f'(2) + \frac{1}{2}(x-2)^2 f''(2) + \cdots = f(2) + 2(x-2)^2 +\cdots $$
where $(x-2)$ is small.

Another is to explain in detail that:

- $f'(2) = 0$ means that the graph is roughly flat at $2$.
- $f''(2) > 0$ means that $f' > 0$ to the right of $2$ but $f' < 0$ to the left.
- Therefore the graph comes down to this point from the left, and increases away from it to the right.
- Therefore the graph has a \_/ shape.

*Edit*: In response to your comment about $f''$, my usual way of thinking about it is this: it is the rate of change of $f'$. Hence $f''>0$ tells us **the function's slope is gradually bending upwards**. This means, since it's flat where $f'(2)=0$, it must be curved in a smile shape.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I would up vote your answer, but I don't have enough points yet.

Comment: Can you explain this:  You said, $f''(2) > 0$ means that $f'> 0$ to the right of 2 but $f'< 0$ to the left.  This may be a really dumb question, but how do you know that $f' < 0$ to the left?

Comment: I can't "draw" this in a comment, but many instructors teach a little memory aid for the "second derivative test", which we'd now call a "smiley": for $f''(x) > 0$, draw two plus signs over an upward-turned arc (a slimey representing a local minimum); for $f''(x) < 0$, make two minus signs over a downward-turned arc (a local maximum "frownie")...

Comment: Heh... I like that..  what happens, though, if $f'' = 0$?

Comment: @nkon - For the same reason that $f'>0$ tells us the slope is upwards, so $f$ both bigger to the right and smaller to the left! Everything tells us about both the right and left, neither is special. Also, if $f''=f'=0$ then the next term in the *Taylor expansion* I mentioned comes into play, and it has the same shape as the cubic $f'''(2) (x-2)^3$ does, and so on. (So $f'''(2)>0$ means it increases to the right and decreases to the left - you could also work this about by saying that going right, $f''$ gets a bit bigger than 0, which makes $f'$ a bit bigger, which makes $f$ bigger.)